# Reference Request: Nadis, Chakras in Hindu (or preferably Indian) nomenclature

Tags: yoga, tantra, reference-request, buddhism, chakras

Consider this question as a reference request.

Nadis are branch points corresponding to nerves in the physical body. The branch point of Nadis is called Chakra. Primary nadi involves - Sushumna Nadi along the spine, and primary chakras as shat chakras broadly.

Now the problem is that these objects (or yantras) are often used in Tantra - activating nadis, activating chakras, balancing chakras, activating nadis/chakras, chakra siddhis, cleaning chakras, clearing nadis, etc. get often hard to answer due to lack of proper references. There are certain Upanishads that roughly use elements from tantra - like these, but there is no proper reference that properly systematically starts with these.

Now the questions on the website have askers that often use these nomenclatures that aren't Indian or aligned to Hindu/Buddhist concepts - like shifting nadis/chakras, clearing, and siddhis associated with them. There are also different names associated with such too - sacral chakra, root chakras, etc. used by Western/theosophical societies.

In my opinion, I don't find this problematic, but, a proper answer requires **Indian origin texts** like - Agamas, etc. that can be used to translate them into Indian concepts of Chakras and then answer them through citing them.

The majority of the agamas that I've come across - Shat Charkra Nipurna, etc don't cover the details of such nomenclature of such. Are there any good agamas/texts that can be used as a central text for quoting while answering these questions in detail? The majority of my knowledge came from multiple different people in lecture format, so I find very uncomfortable answering these questions without sources.

Thank You.

---

PS - Cite books with Indian origin, any Hindu/Buddhist text would work, BUT they shouldn't follow theosophical nomenclature and terms.

Edit: The number of chakras and their nomenclature varies well within Indian texts too, that's not a problem. I'm more concerned about the procedure and practices.

Comment: It would be helpful to take dīkṣā from a proper ācārya/ācāryā, who can guide you through both practice and procedure.

Comment: @Bingming I've already taken diksha and have been practicing for years. The problem is that I cannot use my own source of knowledge to write answers here, I'd need to cite a text that is commonly accepted within the community.

Comment: I see, so you are familiar with the concepts, but not well versed with the terminology to explain them in writing ?

Comment: @Bingming I'm familiar with concepts, but not the modern theosophical terminology used. Second, I'm not familiar with the texts that I can use to back my answers here.

Comment: Well, you should avoid the theosophical terminology, because that’s messed up. Instead, you should rely on the Sanskrit terminology in āgamaśāstras. And you can only become familiar with that, by reading them or doing their śravaṇa under a guru.

Comment: @Bingming I'm familiar with very few agamas - siva sutras, shatcharkanipurna, yoga upanishads, dattatreya yoga samhita, etc. There's another very good book that I wanted in english (but don't have a translation) is yajnavalkyayoga samhita. My teacher was well versed with that. I'm having a bit lack of books on having to write more answers about chakras and nadis this time.

Comment: You can get many pdfs online on Internet archive, it would be better to avoid English translations though

Comment: @Bingming In the context of Yoga, English translations aren't very problematic. But what I lack is texts. For example there are 16 minor nadis in skull and I'm yet to find a good book referencing that.